# Extremely difficult 11 month old baby

Tags: infant, behavior, crying

I have an extremely fussy baby boy. He just turned 11 months old, while he's never been an "easy" baby, the past month he has been awful.  He sleeps well and eats well, but when up all he does is cry and whine. He will have a day here and there when he is OK, but the majority of my days with have been very hard. Not only does he cry, he makes these whining noises that can last for hours on end.

It seems like no matter what I do he is not happy.  Don't get me wrong, he can be a very smiley happy baby at moments, but it never lasts. It is like there is no in between with him. He is either laughing and smiling or crying and whining.

I have taken him to the Dr and he can't find anything wrong with him.  I am at my wits end. This is really taking a toll on me.  He has 6 teeth already and was miserable when he got his first, so I don't know if it's his teeth bothering him, but any insight would be helpful .

Comment: Has his behavior when getting the last 6 teeth been similar to his current behavior?  If so, have you tried anything to soothe the pain of teething?  Do you use a "pacifier" a.k.a. "binky"?  Does that help, if you do?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you find the right solution. This is going to be about trial and error. All that baby knows is that he is uncomfortable with some stimulus or some need that he is not getting. I mean, think about it. Babies are not thinking about the woes of the world, so we know *that*'s not getting him down.  Babies don't get mad at *people*, so he's not *mad* at *you*... or anyone else. He's expressing either *frustration*, (not getting a desire/need met) or *discomfort*.

If he is having *internal* discomfort and has no other symptoms, i.e. fever, digestive, or neurological---and you've gotten his ears checked out for pain/infection---and his labs are ok... girl, you can't do anything except wait for that to pass, and it will. If it's *external* discomfort, just try to figure out what it is. If he's not blue from being cold, pink from being overheated, sweating from being too hot, or shivering from being too cold--and he's *dry*, put that baby down within eye shot and give him some kind of mobile to watch--some sort of stimulus, and go do something else.

You cannot focus on him so much that you aren't getting anything else done. Here's something I did with mine... very helpful... I got a podaegi and carried her around on my back all the time... put her to sleep and freed up my hands-- -you can look it up on youtube and try different variations.  Good luck with that baby-- he's just *opinionated*!

Comment: Please be nice. The all caps are considered shouting. If you feel the need to emphasize, italics are preferred (see the formatting options on editing) and this answer should be edited to remove them, as well as the "wall of text" (paragraph breaks improve readability.) Thanks.

Comment: @anongoodnurse made an edit along those lines, could probably still use more work but it should be a lot less egregious.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I appreciate the comments--are you a moderator on this site? I just want to know how much attention I need to give your constructive criticisms...I actually like putting my emphasis points IN CAPS, I think its better than *italics*, I personally think the etiquette needs to change. You know, that DOES happen over time....sometimes etiquette changes. As to Mr. Danikov: I had to look up what egregious even meant!!! Talk to your audience, homz! Thank yall both for the input...I'm new and didn't know I'd be critiqued like that....can yall just once again, please state your authorit

Comment: Welcome to Parenting, Jade :) Take a look at the [tour]; the StackExchange sites work on a general principle of communal contribution to helping improve answers through suggestions [as well as editing](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/editing). It's not necessarily a matter of who gets authority to declare something, it's more that we're working together :)

Comment: Thanks..and how do I accept yall's productive edits? I saw the changes, and (hate to admit this) they look better than what I wrote.  So, how do I say, oh, yeah, kewl.....and accept the changes?

Comment: Edits are reviewed either by other users or by the answer OP; this one already was reviewed :) If an edit gets approved that you don't like, then you can edit yourself or roll it back. You can also use [meta] to ask questions about features of the site (or edits of a question and so on) that you don't understand, or just find somebody in [chat] and ask for advice or information.